# Finite field $\mathbb Z_7$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

> Consider the field $\mathbb Z_7$. Find all $x\in \Bbb Z_7$ such that $x^2 = 2$.

Is there a way to do this without trial and error? Answer is $x = 3$ and $x = 4$.

Comment: there are 7 elements, 2 of which obviously don't work. How much easier is it gonna get? Anyway, quadratic reciprocity may be worth looking into

Comment: You might observe that $3^2 = 4^2 = 2$ and $4 =  -3$  in $\Bbb Z_7$.